# How do you apply a style to only one div in the HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I had working code until I tried to make the style.css page apply only to a certain div on the index.html file. This is the current code I have: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LEXxeM

All that I did (which made it stop working) was completely wrap the style.css page in "adder { }", and put all the code in the body in a div tag.

Any ideas as to why this was an incorrect step?

In case codepen can't be accessed, below is the code.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--

-->
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/styleok.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/init.js"></script>





    </head>



   <body>


        <div class="adder">
        <div id="container">
            <header>
                 <h1>Task ListO</h1>
              <a href="#" id="clear">Clear all</a>

            </header>

            <section id="taskIOSection">
                    <div id="formContainer">
                    <form id="taskEntryForm">
                        <input id="taskInput" placeholder="Add your interests here..." />
                    </form>
                </div>
                <ul id="taskList"></ul>
            </section>
        </div>
        </div>






    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400, 300, 600);


    adder {

     * {
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
    }
    body {
      background:url('');
        background-color:#2a2a2a;
        font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    }
    #container {
        background-color: #111216;
        color:#999999;
        width:350px;
        margin: 50px auto auto auto;
        padding-bottom:12px;
    }
    #formContainer {
        padding-top:12px
    }
    #taskIOSection {
    }
    #taskInput {

        font-size:14px;
        font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        height:36px;
        width:311px;
        border-radius:100px;
        background-color:#202023;
        border:0;
        color:#fff;
        display:block;
        padding-left:15px;
       -webkit-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
      -ms-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
      -o-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
    }
    #taskInput:focus{
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 1pt 1pt #999999;
     background-color:#111216; 
      outline:none;
    }
    ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
        color: #333333;
        font-style:italic;
        /* padding-left:10px; */
    }
    :-moz-placeholder {
        /* Firefox 18- */
        color: #333333;
        font-style:italic;
    }
    ::-moz-placeholder {
        /* Firefox 19+ */
        color: #333333;
        font-style:italic;
    }
    :-ms-input-placeholder {
        color: #333333;
        font-style:italic;
    }
    header {
        margin-top:0;
        background-color:#F94D50;
    width:338px;
    height:48px;
    padding-left:12px;
}
header h1 {
    font-size:25px;
    font-weight:300;
    color:#fff;
    line-height:48px;
  width:50%;
  display:inline;
}
header a{

  width:40%;
  display:inline;
  line-height:48px;
}
#taskEntryForm {
    background-color:#111216;
    width:326px;
    height: 48px;
    border-width:0px;
    padding: 0px 12px 0px 12px;
    font-size:0px;
}
#taskList {
    width: 350px;
    margin:auto;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:600;
}
ul li {
    background-color:#17181D;
    height:48px;
    width:314px;
    padding-left:12px;
    margin:0 auto 10px auto;
    line-height:48px;
    list-style:none;
  overflow:hidden;
  white-space:nowrap;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
}    

}
```

JS:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
                        var i = 0;
                        for (i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
                            var taskID = "task-" + i;
     $('#taskList').append("<li id='" + taskID + "'>" + localStorage.getItem(taskID) + "</li>");
                        }
                        $('#clear').click(function () {
                            localStorage.clear();
                        });
                        $('#taskEntryForm').submit(function () {
                            if ($('#taskInput').val() !== "") {
                                var taskID = "task-" + i;
                                var taskMessage = $('#taskInput').val();
                                localStorage.setItem(taskID, taskMessage);
    $('#taskList').append("<li class='task' id='" + taskID + "'>" + taskMessage + "</li>");
                                var task = $('#' + taskID);
                                task.css('display', 'none');
                                task.slideDown();
                                $('#taskInput').val("");
                                i++;
                            }
                            return false;
                        });

                        $('#taskList').on("click", "li", function (event) {
                            self = $(this);
                            taskID = self.attr('id');
                            localStorage.removeItem(taskID);
                            self.slideUp('slow', function () {
                                self.remove();
                            });

                        });


                    });
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why did you wrap all the CSS code in adder { ? That's going to cause incorrect CSS surely... If you want to just style one element, assign it an ID, and create a rule for that in your stylesheet.

Comment: I wrapped it that way because I'm trying to figure out how to make only one div in the HTML use the style.css page, rather than having every div that I make get styled from it. So I thought that wrapping it with an "adder" name would allow me to call "adder" for just one div.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally for these one off or different pages I would consider adding a style class directly to the body tag, rather than wrapping all the content in an additional div, since it serves no semantic purposes and it is really for styling only purposes.

```
<body class="adder">
  <div id="container">
    <!-- other code -->
  </code>
</body>
```

Then add some specific styles for your custom styles pages in the same stylesheet. These need to be declared **after** the original definition.

```
/* adder overrides */
.adder #container {
    background-color: #0094FF;
}

.adder header {
    background-color:#00FF7F;
}

.adder #taskEntryForm {
    background-color:#0043FF;
}
```

Since the style `.adder #container` is more specific in this instance this is what will get applied. It's a compound set of styles, so first the stlye `#container` will be applied and then the styles from `.adder #container` will override anything that is specific in this class.

If you are using Google Chrome then press F12 and you can see the style chain in the Elements tab (as well as change them in that window for learning/demo purposes)

[Demo on CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PwxWXN)

Answer (score 1):

your CSS syntax is incorrect. Unless you were working with SASS in which case it would be ok. Remove adder.

I also see no point to wrapping your CSS in this adder class? It add's nothing HTML/CSS wise. If you explain what you're actually trying to achieve then maybe we can assist a bit more.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Here is what I am trying to achieve: having 2 different divs in the HTML that have different styles. I don't want every DIV that I make to use that style.css sheet. My end goal is to have two different style sheets, and two different divs that each use a different style sheet. (It's my first time trying to make a website, btw...)

Comment: Don't use two stylesheets, stick to one (it will keep the resources count down when loading the site). What you could do, is on each page, add a class to the body tag that relates to the page. Then you can style eachelement within the body tag for each individual page.

Comment: Ok, that's absolute fine :) The issue being is by wrapping all of that it creates incorrect syntax for CSS. If you were to use SASS this would support what your trying to do. I'd reccomend looking into that if you wish to do this how your doing it now still. 

Otherwise I'd recommend simply adding an additional class onto your divs to differentiate the two.

Comment: Okay, great! Thank you all for the help very much! Time to forge ahead more bravely =]

Answer (score 0):

Below is a simple example of using css.

```css
#outer{
  background-color:grey;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
}
#inner{
border:1px solid green;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  margin:10px;
}

#outer > #inner{
  color:red;
  line-height:100px;
  text-align:center;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
   <div id="inner">
     Hello
   </div>
</div>
<div id="inner">
  Hi
</div>
```

I have a div with an id outer and two divs with an id inner out of which one is inside the outer div and the other is outside the outer div.

The css for inner div which is inside the outer div is written inside `#outer > #inner{}`

and the css for both div with an id - inner is written inside `#inner{}`

I have given a margin of 10 px for inner div but that isn't applied for the one which is inside the outer div.

this happened because the code which is inside `#outer > #inner{}` is overriding the code which is inside `#inner{}`

You can target a css based on id using '#' or class using '.' or html elements or Pseudo-class.

you can get a complete reference for css in this [link](http://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/)

Comment: That was a very helpful demonstration. Thank you!! and I'm looking at codrops now